# How to stop a future delayed when I change the class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a `future.delayed` in the `iniState` to show an alert dialog but sometimes I change the class before this time is the problem is that the alert is shown in another class 
so I want to stop the timer when I leave the class that's the code of the timernew

```
Future.delayed(Duration (seconds: 6), () {
      if(a==0)
      {showDialog(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
            double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
         return   Dialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)), //this right here
                child: Container(
                  height: 110,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    child: ListView(
                      children: ListTile.divideTiles(context: context, tiles: [
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            'Vous n\'etes pas connecter a BLuetooth essayer de le faire et repetez le test',

                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: null,
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text('OK',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),)
                          ,onTap: (){
                            globals.Data.etatbluetooth('0');
                            Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => resultat()),
        );
                        },
                        )



                      ]).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            );

      }
      );}
      else{
        globals.Data.etatbluetooth('1');
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => resultat()),
        );
      }
    });
```

so how can i stop it if i leave the class any help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know, there is no actual way to cancel the `Future.delay` task in the dart, but I would suggest you use `Timer` instead of it, which will behave similarly to your purpose

**Example:**

```
 Timer _timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 6), () {
       print('Called after interval');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }
```

**Note:** Initialize `Timer` in `initState` and cancel it in `dispose` method.

Comment: it didn't give me a result the same probleme

Comment: @MohamedBorheneDhahri: you mentioned you are leaving class? what does it mean? can you target me to that code?